# Algorithm for Human Towering

Tags: algorithm, sorting, dynamic-programming

In [Cracking the Coding Interview, Fourth Edition](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Cracking-Coding-Interview-Fourth-Edition/dp/145157827X/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1374531842&sr=8-2&keywords=cracking%20the%20coding%20interview), there is such a problem:

> A circus is designing a tower routine consisting of people standing
>   atop one anoth- er’s shoulders For practical and aesthetic reasons,
>   each person must be both shorter and lighter than the person below him
>   or her Given the heights and weights of each person in the circus,
>   write a method to compute the largest possible number of people in
>   such a tower.
>
> EXAMPLE: Input (ht, wt): (65, 100) (70, 150) (56, 90)
>   (75, 190) (60, 95) (68, 110)
>
> Output: The longest tower is length 6 and
>   includes from top to bottom: (56, 90) (60,95) (65,100) (68,110)
>   (70,150) (75,190)

---

Here is its **solution in the book**

> Step 1 Sort all items by height first, and then by weight This means that if all the heights are unique, then the items will be sorted by their height If heights are the same, items will be sorted by their weight
>
> Step 2 Find the longest sequence which contains increasing heights and increasing weights
>   To do this, we:
>
> a) Start at the beginning of the sequence Currently, max_sequence is empty
>
> b) If, for the next item, the height and the weight is not greater than those of the previous item, we mark this item as “unfit”
>
> c) If the sequence found has more items than “max sequence”, it becomes “max sequence”
>
> d) After that the search is repeated from the “unfit item”, until we reach the end of the original sequence

---

I have some questions about its solutions.

**Q1**

I believe this solution is wrong.

For example

`(3,2) (5,9) (6,7) (7,8)`

Obviously, `(6,7)` is an unfit item, but how about `(7,8)`? According to the solution, it is NOT unfit as its h and w are bother bigger than `(6,7)`, however, it cannot be considered into the sequence, because `(7,8)` does not fit `(5,9)`.

Am I right?

If I am right, what is the fix?

**Q2**

I believe even if there is a fix for the above solution, the style of the solution will lead to at least `O(n^2)`, because it need to iterate again and again, according to step 2-d.

So is it possible to have a O(nlogn) solution?

Comment: Clarify. Step b says "... mark this item..." but is "this" item the "previous" or the "next" item from the first part of the step? Secondly, if you find an "unfit" item, is it skipped? Does it end the sequence? I also don't understand what "the search is repeated" in step D means.

Comment: The algorithm may or may not be correct, but the way it's described seems to leave it impervious to most attempts at understanding it... If that's verbatim from the book, I'd get rid of it.

Comment: Echoing what JacobRaihle said, that book doesn't seem to have been proofread very well. I remember reading the first few chapters and finding a few errors in the solutions/edge cases that were uncovered. It does a good job of outlining topics you should cover in your prep, but it didn't seem particularly authoritative in any of the information it covered.

Comment: I had a problem whenever I needed to implement the IComparable method ToCompare, in C#, should return an int, to check if two objects are higher, smaller or bigger than each other, to define the comparison criteria, because you can have 5 options:
(H1 > H2 and W1 < W2), 
(H1 > H2 and W1 > W2), 
(H1 < H2 and W1 < W2),
(H1 < H2 and W1 > W2),
(H1 == H2 and W1 == W2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem with dynamic programming.

Sort the troupe by height. For simplicity, assume all the heights h_i and weights w_j are distinct. Thus h_i is an increasing sequence.

We compute a sequence T_i, where T_i is a tower with person i at the top of maximal size. T_1 is simply {1}. We can deduce subsequent T_k from the earlier T_j  — find the largest tower T_j that can take k's weight (w_j < w_k) and stand k on it.

The largest possible tower from the troupe is then the largest of the T_i.

This algorithm takes O(n**2) time, where n is the cardinality of the troupe.

Comment: by O(n**2), you mean O(n^2)?

Comment: @JacksonTale yes, slip of the parseltongue, that's Python syntax.

Comment: @ColonelPanic: What if the heights and weights are not unique?

Answer (score 0):

Tried solving this myself, did not meant to give 'ready made solution', but still giving , more to check my own understanding and if my code(Python) is ok and would work of all test cases. I tried for 3 cases and it seemed to work of correct answer.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#This function takes a list of tuples. Tuple(n):(height,weight) of nth person
def htower_len(ht_wt):
    ht_sorted = sorted(ht_wt,reverse=True)
    wt_sorted = sorted(ht_wt,key=lambda ht_wt:ht_wt[1])
    max_len = 1 

    len1 = len(ht_sorted)
    i=0
    j=0
    while i < (len1-1):
        if(ht_sorted[i+1][1] < ht_sorted[0][1]):
            max_len = max_len+1
        i=i+1           

    print "maximum tower length :" ,max_len

###Called above function with below sample app code.
testcase =1 
print "Result of Test case ",testcase   
htower_len([(5,75),(6.7,83),(4,78),(5.2,90)])

testcase = testcase + 1
print "Result of Test case ",testcase   
htower_len([(65, 100),(70, 150),(56, 90),(75, 190),(60, 95),(68, 110)])

testcase = testcase + 1
print "Result of Test case ",testcase   

htower_len([(3,2),(5,9),(6,7),(7,8)])
```

Comment: Is this a dynamic programming as well?

Comment: No, this isn't dynamic programming approach.

Answer (score 0):

> For example
>
> (3,2) (5,9) (6,7) (7,8)
>
> Obviously, (6,7) is an unfit item, but how about (7,8)?

In answer to your Question - the algorithm first runs starting with 3,2 and gets the sequence (3,2) (5,9) marking (6,7) and (7,8) as unfit.

It then starts again on (6,7) (the first unfit) and gets (6,7) (7,8), and that makes the answer 2. Since there are no more "unfit" items, the sequence terminates with maximum length 2.

Comment: but if you dropped (5,9) from consideration you could get a run of 3. So this is not a very good algorithm or it's not well explained.

Comment: Yes, its a bit strange that this got into a book when it obviously doesn't work as stated.

Comment: I mean, I can think of several ways to make a working algorithm, but I am not sure that any of them represent the spirit of what the author was trying to get at.

Answer (score 0):

After first sorting the array by height and weight, my code checks what the largest tower would be if we grabbed any of the remaining tuples in the array (and possible subsequent tuples). In order to avoid re-computing sub-problems, `solution_a` is used to store the optimal max length from the tail of the `input_array`.

The `beginning_index` is the index from which we can consider grabbing elements from (the index from which we can consider people who could go below on the human stack), and `beginning_tuple` refers to the element/person higher up on the stack.

This solution runs in O(nlogn) to do the sort. The space used is O(n) for the `solution_a` array and the copy of the `input_array`.

```
def determine_largest_tower(beginning_index, a, beginning_tuple, solution_a):
    # base case
    if beginning_index >= len(a):
        return 0
    if solution_a[beginning_index] != -1:   # already computed
        return solution_a[beginning_index]

    # recursive case
    max_len = 0
    for i in range(beginning_index, len(a)):
        # if we can grab that value, check what the max would be
        if a[i][0] >= beginning_tuple[0] and a[i][1] >= beginning_tuple[1]:
            max_len = max(1 + determine_largest_tower(i+1, a, a[i], solution_a), max_len)
    solution_a[beginning_index] = max_len
    return max_len

def algorithm_for_human_towering(input_array):
    a = sorted(input_array)
    return determine_largest_tower(0, a, (-1,-1), [-1] * len(a))

a = [(3,2),(5,9),(6,7),(7,8)]
print algorithm_for_human_towering(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to approach the problem altogether with code;

**Algorithm**

1. Sorting first by height and then by width

> Sorted array:
> [(56, 90), (60, 95), (65, 100), (68, 110), (70, 150), (75, 190)]

2. Finding the length of the longest increasing subsequence of weights

> Why the longest subsequence of weights is the answer?
> The people are sorted by increasing height,
> so when we are finding a subsequence of people with increasing weights too
> these selected people would satisfy our requirement as they are both in increasing order of heights and weights and therefore can form a human tower.

> For example:
> [(56, 90) (60,95) (65,100) (68,110) (70,150) (75,190)]

**Efficient Implementation**

In the attached implementation we maintain a list of increasing numbers and uses `bisect_left`, which is implemented under the hood using binary search, to find the proper index for insertion.

Please Note; The sequence generated by `longest_increasing_sequence` method might not be the actual longest subsequence, however, the *length* of it - will surely be as the length of the longest increasing subsequence.

Kindly refer to [Longest increasing subsequence Efficient algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence#Efficient_algorithms) for more details.

The overall time complexity is O(n log(n)) as desired.

**Code**

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def human_tower(height, weight):
    def longest_increasing_sequence(A, get_property):
        lis = []
        for i in range(len(A)):
            x = get_property(A[i])
            i = bisect_left(lis, x)
            if i == len(lis):
                lis.append(x)
            else:
                lis[i] = x
        return len(lis)
    # Edge case, no people
    if 0 == len(height):
        return 0
    # Creating array of heights and widths
    people = [(h, w) for h, w in zip(height, weight)]
    # Sorting array first by height and then by width
    people.sort()
    # Returning length longest increasing sequence
    return longest_increasing_sequence(people, lambda t : t[1])

assert 6 == human_tower([65,70,56,75,60,68], [100,150,90,190,95,110])
```